# Per-request scope with ASP.NET 5 and built-in DI container

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm investigating the topic of DI in ASP.NET 5, and I faced such a problem - I don't understand how to create a new instance of a service per request.

I use the code:

```
services.AddScoped<ValueStore>();
```

And inside my middlewares I grab the value:

```
var someValueStore = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ValueStore>();
```

Full code is available [here](https://github.com/kosmakoff/VnextDiDemo)

And my problem is: while I expect this service to be renewed on each request, it doesn't happen, and it behaves as if it was registered as `AddSingleton()`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What if you inject `ValueStore` in the `Invoke` method of the middleware? `app.ApplicationServices` might not contain the request-scoped services and return a singleton instance in stead.

Comment: You should be having access to `HttpContext` in your middleware and in which case you can get access to `RequestServices` and resolve your per-request service.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`app.ApplicationServices` does not provide a request-scoped `IServiceProvider`. It will return a singleton instance of `ValueStore` when you use `GetService<>()`. You have two options here:

Use `HttpContext.RequestServices`:

```
var someValueStore = context.RequestServices.GetService<ValueStore>();
```

Or inject `ValueStore` in the `Invoke` method of a middleware:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ValueStore valueStore)
{
    await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Random value = {valueStore.SomeValue}");
    await _next(httpContext);
}
```

I cloned your repo and this works.

Comment: This code worked as expected. However the answer to my primary question happened to be: I should have used RequestServices instead of ApplicationServices in first place. In ApplicationServices no Lifetime options make any difference and all 3 of them behave like if it was Singleton.

Comment: @kosmakoff I mentioned `RequestServices` already. I made the two options more clear now.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's my poor attention, I only saw the big chunk of code and completely missed the `RequestServices` reference below. Thanks for examples, now everything is more clear for me. I wish I could find the answer before I asked this question.

Comment: +1 one hundred times! But please, tell me how did you know this? No documentation, no samples, confusing property names... Are you a diviner or am I loosing any good source of documentation?

Comment: @Vi100 I had a similar issue like this, figured it out by debugging in the dependency injection framework.